# Git, Heroku, node Js [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)

Tags: node.js, git, heroku

I just finished a Node Js project that I would like to deploy on Heroku.

But when pushing, I get the following message:

```
$ git push heroku master

To https://git.heroku.com/helpmediy.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/helpmediy.git'
```

I've been looking for several times, I come across forums that date back several years without a working solution

Answer (score 0):

There are many possible problems that may have occurred. Make sure you are not pushing any random repo to Heroku and it is configured for node app. Check out this  `dashboard.heroku.com/apps/{your App name}/activity` and follow the steps. If it detects a node.js app there may be a problem with the build.
Another fix that helps many developers is to make a new branch and try pushing your code to that like:-
`git checkout -b new-branch`
and then
`git push heroku new-branch`